# Transitioning to an already contained UIViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a vertical UIScrollView with several 'cards', nested UIViewControllers (via container views), each with their own state.  Some of these cards can be expanded to take up the entire screen (what I'd effectively consider a full view controller transition) and later collapsed back to its original size.  Ideally, we'd be segueing into these views, but apparently, transitioning into an already displayed view controller triggers an assertion.  I'm currently experimenting with just changing the parent UIScrollView's contentOffset and any given card's bounds property upon expand/collapse, but this is proving to be a bit of a p.i.t.a. from several angles.

Is there any way to utilize a proper UIViewController transition for this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to utilize a proper UIViewController transition for this?

Consider instantiating a new instance of the same type of view controller, configuring it with the same data, and transitioning to that instead. That way you don't have to mess around with removing the controller from the container and putting it back later.